# Java project in Eclipse. Feature to open Declaration or Implementation using `ctrl+click` or `F3` is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, path, ide, buildpath

When i import a web application in eclipse enterprise it works but the control click features don't work. Even the code it seems as not recognized for the most part of it (in fact it is all black and some part, like return public, private, the letters are purple).

Basic question could be How to Update Java Project `Source Code` path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I the code is not recognized seems the code is in the project but not configured as source code.

Check if the project -> Properties -> Build path -> tab "Source"

contains your java files.

Comment: i have included all the files to the source of the build path and now it works thank you <3